# Making Worklight 6.0 generated native android applications faster?

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I'm using IBM Worklight 6.0 to develop a cross platform application. There is no provision(as far as my knowledge) about the way the native applications are generated by worklight.
Is it possible to make these applications run faster?

And do these applications cache the data(say images in the applications), locally in the mobile applications so that the App runs faster the next time its invoked?

If not is there any way to do that?

Comment: Please explain the scenario you are experiencing. "run faster" means nothing. Explain. Do you mean the startup? During runtime? etc... also mention the EXACT build number of Worklight 6.0 that you are using.

Comment: Yes, I mean during Startup. Applications with more css and js makes my app slower. Build : 6.0.0.20130909-1459

Comment: Do you mean only the First time the app is launched, or any launch of the app? Which device? Which Android OS?

Comment: Every time the app is launched it starts off slowly with IBM Splash screen for about 20 seconds. Build is : 6.0.0.20130909-1459 . The Device is Micromax Canvas 2. Android os : Jellybean(4.2)

Comment: does using Worklight 6.0.0.2 (see my aswer) help? Can this question be resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Update to the recently released Worklight 6.0.0.2](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24036987); your initial start-up time should decrease considerably. See if it helps.

Comment: Just as a reason why: In 6.0.0.2 and later, Worklight now loads resources dynamically as needed instead of copying all resources on first run. For apps with lots of resources or large resources, this will cause a large delay in versions < 6.0.0.2. So if your app needs a javascript file, image file, css file for example, it is copied the moment is needed instead.